# space between the logo and the company name

Tags: css

I want to increase the space between the logo of my company and the text of the company. Below is my code :

```
<div class="navbar">
            <img class="logo" src="Images/logo.png" width="60" runat="server" /><h1 style="color:white;">This is my company name</h1>

        </div>
```

This is the stylesheet:

```
 @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar {
        display: flex;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        height: 70px;
        align-items: center;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        margin-right:200px;
        flex-direction:row;
    }
```

below is the image of the logo and the company name:

[image]

Comment: You specified `justify-content: space-between`. Try not setting this property and just define `gap: 10px` or however much you need.

Comment: gap or margin right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure to use `justify-content: space-between;` if you use flexbox, also here is **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/callmenikk/d74h8bfn/13/)** link and you can check on your own how it looks like, also I included second version of mine where I used `justify-content: space-around;` and `padding` to center navbar content and give them same space from corners

Comment: If I want to reduce the space between company logo and the name of the company. How can I do that with your stylesheet.

Comment: I called my version navbar class `navbar-two`, you will need to create new class for example call it `container` and put your image and text in there and do same thing what I did in previous code **this container must be in navbar-two class** after that on `navbar-two` still use `display: flex; align-items: center;  justify-content: center;` to place this container in center, and for container `padding: 0 190px; width: 100%; display: flex; align-items: center;  justify-content: space-between;` to make contents closer change padding's second value because first one is up and bottom

Comment: and second one is left and right  and this is what we need, maybe I made confusion in your head and I will still left **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/callmenikk/qjvbc6Lk/5/)** link and check on your own what I made

Answer (score 0):

you are using `justify-content: space-between;` which will share the space between your child elements.
remove it and use margin-right on the logo

Comment: I tried using margin-right. now the logo is overlapping the company name. I posted the image in my original post. I also posted the style sheet.

Comment: Remove the inline style on the h2 for negative margin and the new margin-right of 20px applied to the logo will properly push that title to the right. BTW this title should most probably be an h1 not an h2.

Comment: I removed the inline style on the h2 of the negative margin. I also changed the h2 to h1.still the company name is very close to the logo. almost no pace between them.

Comment: add flex-direction:row

Comment: I made all the changes suggested above still the space between the company logo and company name is almost nothing. I posted the image above including the style sheet.